# R - New Factor Variable based in imediatly previous row and other columns. Optimization Ifelse

Tags: r

I've been searching arround SO, and other data science and programming blogs, but i haven't found an answer for my specific need. So, if you find this question duplicate please be kind enough and point me to source of the information and close/delete this question.

My real data will have several thousands of rows, so i display here only a small set of fictional data, that resembles very similarly my original data:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
  Year = c(2014,2015,2016,2017,2007,2008,2009,2010,2016,2017),
  CmSm = c(1,2,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0),
  Index = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2)
)
```

The Dataset i would like to get in the end is:

```
Dataout <- data.frame(
     ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
     Year = c(2014,2015,2016,2017,2007,2008, 2009,2010,2016,2017),
     CmSm = c(1,2,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0),
     Index = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2),
     Cassification = c("New", "Existing", "Existing", "Lost", "New", "Lost","","Returning", "New","Lost")
 )
```

My best attempt so far is as follows:

```
Dataout$Status <- ave( Dataout$CmSm, 
 Dataout$ID, 
 FUN = function(x) ifelse( Dataout$Index == 1, "New", ifelse( x[-1] == 0 & x > 0, "Returning", ifelse( x[-1] == 0 & x == 0, "", ifelse( x[-1] > 0 & x == 0, "Lost", "Existing" ) ) ) ) )
```

However this attempt has 2 problems:

1. Its classifying wrongly;
2. When i use this code in my original data, with thousands and thousands of rows, R does 15 minutes of computation and don't retreive any results (I imagine that ifelse is not helping...), not to mention that the memory allocated to the process is ridiculously high.

The explanation of the problem at hand, and rules of classification:

Given a list of item ID's, the Year and the index of the item ID, I would like to classify those items in the folowing categories: "New", "Existing","Returning","Lost" and "" or null or NA.
The rules for this classification are as follow (CmSm-1 represents the imediate previsous value relative to the present CmSm value):

If Index == 1 then "New".

If Index > 1 then:

if CmSm-1 == 0 and CmSm > 0 then "Returning".

If CmSm-1 == 0 and CmSm == 0 then "" -> this resembles the case where the object had no events registered.

If CmSm-1 > 0 and CmSm > 0 then "Existing".

If CmSm-1 > 0 and CmSm == 0 then "Lost".

Please let me know if you found my rules explanation confusing, so i can have a chance to clarify them for you.

Thank you in advance, for any help you could provide.
Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use single vectorized conditional steps?

```
library(dplyr)

Data$Classification <- NA
Data$Classification[Data$Index == 1] <- "New"
Data$Classification[Data$Index > 1 & lag(Data$CmSm) == 0 & Data$CmSm > 0] <- "Returning"
Data$Classification[Data$Index > 1 & lag(Data$CmSm) == 0 & Data$CmSm == 0] <- ""
Data$Classification[Data$Index > 1 & lag(Data$CmSm) > 0 & Data$CmSm > 0] <- "Existing"
Data$Classification[Data$Index > 1 & lag(Data$CmSm) > 0 & Data$CmSm == 0] <- "Lost"

> Data
   ID Year CmSm Index Classification
1   1 2014    1     1            New
2   1 2015    2     2       Existing
3   1 2016    1     3       Existing
4   1 2017    0     4           Lost
5   2 2007    1     1            New
6   2 2008    0     2           Lost
7   2 2009    0     3               
8   2 2010    1     4      Returning
9   3 2016    1     1            New
10  3 2017    0     2           Lost
```

This has the bonus of being fast as hell.

Microbenchmark of this vs. `case_when`:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
    LAP 1.173902 1.208178 1.580413 1.253404 1.313137 17.07946   100  a 
 h3rm4n 5.538701 5.732692 7.310704 5.913030 6.138168 50.67234   100   b
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% 
  mutate(Classification = case_when(
    Index == 1 ~ "New",
    lag(CmSm) == 0 & CmSm > 0 ~ "Returning",
    lag(CmSm) > 0 & CmSm > 0 ~ "Existing",
    lag(CmSm) > 0 & CmSm == 0 ~ "Lost",
    lag(CmSm) == 0 & CmSm == 0 ~ ""
  ))

   ID Year CmSm Index Classification
1   1 2014    1     1            New
2   1 2015    2     2       Existing
3   1 2016    1     3       Existing
4   1 2017    0     4           Lost
5   2 2007    1     1            New
6   2 2008    0     2           Lost
7   2 2009    0     3               
8   2 2010    1     4      Returning
9   3 2016    1     1            New
10  3 2017    0     2           Lost
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice case for `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```
Data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Status = case_when(Index == 1 ~ "New",
                            lag(CmSm) == 0 & CmSm > 0 ~ "Returning",
                            lag(CmSm) == 0 & CmSm == 0 ~ "",
                            lag(CmSm) > 0 & CmSm > 0 ~ "Existing",
                            lag(CmSm) > 0 & CmSm == 0 ~ "Lost")
         )
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
      ID  Year  CmSm Index Status   
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
 1     1  2014     1     1 New      
 2     1  2015     2     2 Existing 
 3     1  2016     1     3 Existing 
 4     1  2017     0     4 Lost     
 5     2  2007     1     1 New      
 6     2  2008     0     2 Lost     
 7     2  2009     0     3 ""       
 8     2  2010     1     4 Returning
 9     3  2016     1     1 New      
10     3  2017     0     2 Lost
```

Comment: Seems like we were doing the same, but I did not read anything in the OP that made me consider to group by ID

Comment: @Len Looking at the `ave`-code of OP, it has to by group.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R solution. It also uses logical indexes, like the solution by @LAP.

I will recreate `Dataout` because the column of interest is a factor.

```
Dataout <- data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
    Year = c(2014,2015,2016,2017,2007,2008, 2009,2010,2016,2017),
    CmSm = c(1,2,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0),
    Index = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2),
    Cassification = c("New", "Existing", "Existing", "Lost", "New", "Lost","","Returning", "New","Lost"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


inx <- Data$Index == 1
inxCmSm <- Data$CmSm == 0
inxCmSm1 <- c(FALSE, inxCmSm[-length(inxCmSm)])

Data$Status <- ""
Data$Status[inx] <- "New"
Data$Status[!inx & inxCmSm1 & !inxCmSm] <- "Returning"
Data$Status[!inx & !inxCmSm1 & !inxCmSm] <- "Existing"
Data$Status[!inx & !inxCmSm1 & inxCmSm] <- "Lost"

identical(Data$Status, Dataout$Cassification)
#[1] TRUE
```